# Verifying if the jwt token sent from server is the same as the user sent back NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt

I'm making my first API and got a little confused about jwt tokens. The thing is that when a user sign-ins in the app, I check the data in my database and if everything is correct, I send the user jwt token back so they can access their personal information without sending email and password every time. But how can I know if the token user sends back, is the token I sent them? Should I store every token on my server when I send them to the user and then compare them to the ones users send? What is the best practice to handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MongoDB with mongoose you can add a Schema method that generates the jwt and stores it, and another method that checks that token

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
.....
})

UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function () {
  const user = this;
  const token = jwt.sign({ email: user.email }, process.env.JWT_SECRET).toString();
  return token;
};

UserSchema.statics.findByToken = function (token) {
  const user = this;
  const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
  if (decoded.access === 'userEmail') {
    return user.findOne({
      email: decoded.email
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.reject();
  }
};
```

call user.generateAuthToken(); in your controller after verification

and check in the middleware for the token

```
const { User } = require('path/to/model');

const authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.jwtToken;
    const user = await User.findByToken(token);
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject();
    }
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).send(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: I see. Basically, when I receive the token, I should decode it and check if the email and password exist in the database and if they do, I should allow the user to access the requested thing(personal info or something like that).

Comment: You check for email and password in the controller then call the generate method and the middleware check if the token matches

Comment: Oh I get it now. But The token returned by generate method gets stored in the user schema aka in the database right? If the user logs in from another device, the generate method will be called but will it update the previous token value?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the code, though, to store more than one token or to not overwrite the old one, also check passport-jwt